# Solve $y''-6y'+9y=0$ where $y(0)=2$ and $y'(0)=\frac{25}{3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y''-6y'+9y=0\;;y(0)=2\,,y'(0)=\frac{25}{3}$

I keep getting an invalid solution, which I'm sure traces back to some error I made in my calculation.  I just don't see it yet.

First I got the characteristic equation:

$r^2-6r+9=0$ that when factored leaves me with a solution $(r-3)^2$, which means $r=3$

So I get the following general solution:

$y=Ae^{3x}+Bxe^{3x}$, but when attempting to solve these for the particular solution I get $A=2-Bx$ and $25=6$

Comment: You were missing the ' mark for the first derivatives. I've added

Comment: y(0)=2 \to 2=A. And with the other condition you can obtain B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y'=3Ae^{3x}+Be^{3x}+3Bxe^{3x},$ $y'(0)=3A+B=25/3,$ $y(0)=A=2$

$A=2,$ $B=\frac{25}{3}-6=\frac{7}{3}$

Comment: Ahh... forgot to take the derivative, I just applied the same equation to a different solution.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should obtain $A = 2$

$$ y'(x) = 3Ae^{3x} + 3Bxe^{3x}+Be^{3x}$$

$$ \frac{25}{3}= 3A +B$$

$$ B = \frac{7}{3}$$

$$ y(x) = \left(2 + \frac{7}{3}x\right)e^{3x}$$